# Xcode linker error- armv7 slice architecture

Tags: xcode, ios, linker, armv7

Having archive error when want to compile into .ipa

I am using:

Mac OS X Leopard 10.6.7

Xcode 4.3 stable.

Clean and Build in simulator no error.

But

Archive for Adhoc under Latest iOS SDK (iOS 4.3) fail.

Error is as below:

Apple Mach-O Linker Error

setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
..

ld: in /Users/bird/Desktop/IPHONE/test/Classes/Libraries/FlurryLib/libFlurry.a, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice for architecture armv7

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exist code 1

Wondering way to solve it.

Comment: @i need help: what is libFlurry.a? are you trying to use a non compatible architecture for your target? iphone or ipad? There is no Errors in the simulator because libFlurry.a seems compiled well for i386 architecture.

Comment: Did you download last Flurry SDK?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `libFlurry` does not support `armv7s`.

click on the Project, go to *Build Settings* -> find "valid architectures" and remove "armv7s" from the list.